# Get Device IMEI BB10 C++/QML

Tags: c++, qml, blackberry-10

Is there a way to get IMEI of BB10 using qml or cpp? I don't see any documentation for it.

https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/apis/blackberry.identity.html

This did not help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [HarwareInfo](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__device__hardwareinfo.html) API for getting IMEI.

```
#include <bb/device/HardwareInfo>

QString HardwareInfo::imei()
```

You will need permission `"read_device_identifying_information"` to use this API.

And link device lib in pro file,  `LIBS += -lbbdevice`