# How to get IMEI number in blackberry 10 native

Tags: c++, qml, blackberry-10, imei

I am trying to get the Default information of Hardware device in blackberry 10 native, So basically i am trying to access **IMEI** or **SERIAL NUMBER** of the device.

I havetried using following code

**main.cpp**

```
#include "applicationui.hpp"

#include <bb/cascades/Application>
#include <bb/device/HardwareInfo>

#include <QLocale>
#include <QTranslator>

#include <Qt/qdeclarativedebug.h>

using namespace bb::cascades;

Q_DECL_EXPORT int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    qmlRegisterUncreatableType<bb::device::HardwareInfo>("bb.device", 1, 0, "HardwareInfo", "");
    Application app(argc, argv);
    ApplicationUI appui;
    return Application::exec();
}
```

**applicationui.cpp**

```
#include "applicationui.hpp"

#include <bb/cascades/Application>
#include <bb/cascades/QmlDocument>
#include <bb/cascades/AbstractPane>
#include <bb/device/HardwareInfo>
#include <bb/cascades/Label>

using namespace bb::cascades;
using namespace bb::device;

ApplicationUI::ApplicationUI() :
        QObject()
{
    HardwareInfo hwInfo;
    QmlDocument *qml = QmlDocument::create("asset:///main.qml").parent(this);
    qml->setContextProperty("_hardware", &hwInfo);
    AbstractPane *root = qml->createRootObject<AbstractPane>();
    Application::instance()->setScene(root);
}
```

**main.qml**

```
Page {
    Container {
        Label {
            id: showIMEI
        }
        Button {
            text: "Click me"
            onClicked: {
                showIMEI.text = "IMEI = " + _hardware.serialNumber;
                //showIMEI.text = "IMEI = " + _hardware.imei;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but when i click a button i am not getting any data either **IMEI** or **SerialNumber** instead of **imei** or **serial number**.  But always i am getting error like

```
'_hardware' [undefined] is not an object.
```

Note: i have already added following library in my **.PRO**

```
LIBS += -lbbsystem
LIBS += -lbbdevice
LIBS += -lbbdata
```

and following permission to my **XML** file.

```
read_device_identifying_information
```

I have also researched through many link like,

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18688063/get-device-imei-bb10-c-qml), [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18693155/imei-number-in-bb-10-cascades), [Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18693155/imei-number-in-bb-10-cascades) and i have also read the official document of [Blackberry](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__device__hardwareinfo.html#overview) but i am not getting proper way to achieve my task.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,
**main.cpp**

```
#include "applicationui.hpp"

#include <bb/cascades/Application>
#include <bb/device/HardwareInfo.hpp>
#include <QLocale>
#include <QTranslator>

#include <Qt/qdeclarativedebug.h>

using namespace bb::cascades;
using namespace bb::device;

Q_DECL_EXPORT int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    qmlRegisterType<HardwareInfo>("bb.device",1,0,"HardwareInfo");
    Application app(argc, argv);

    // Create the Application UI object, this is where the main.qml file
    // is loaded and the application scene is set.
    ApplicationUI appui;

    // Enter the application main event loop.
    return Application::exec();
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import bb.cascades 1.0
import bb.device 1.0
Page {
    Container {
        Label {
            id: label
            // Localized text with the dynamic translation and locale updates support
            text: qsTr("Hello World") + Retranslate.onLocaleOrLanguageChanged
            textStyle.base: SystemDefaults.TextStyles.BigText
            multiline: true
        }
        Button {
            onClicked: {
                label.text=hardwareinfo.imei 
                console.debug("imei\t"+hardwareinfo.imei)
                console.debug("serialNumber \t"+hardwareinfo.serialNumber)
            }
        }
    }
    attachedObjects:[
        HardwareInfo {
           id: hardwareinfo 
        }
    ]
}
```